# There's any difference between send small single TCP packets and a big one from the receiver side?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a small routine that send some strings trough TCP socket to a remote server from another company and the remote server is not under my control.
My company and the remote company are sharing some data.

They say that they are not receiving all the data but losing some ones, about 15% of the packets are being loosed.

I'm trying to figure out what's happening here.

The packets are relatively small about 70 bytes each.
I'm sending about 300 to 900 packets in the same second every 2 minutes.

I make a sniff with Microsoft Network Monitor 3 and see that some packets are being joined in one big packet of different sizes and some packets are incomplete when that happen.

Plus the checksum, on the sniffer, are marked as incorrect.

This is my code, So I miss something? It is possible to send one small packet(70bytes) by every TCP packet?

```
Try
    If Not IsNumeric(Port) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid port.(" & Port & ")")
    End If
    Dim Msgs() As String
    Dim Tx As New TcpClient()

    Dim stream As NetworkStream = Nothing
    Dim CloseStream As Boolean = False
    Dim LingerMode As New LingerOption(True, 5)

    Tx.NoDelay = True
    Tx.LingerState = LingerMode
    Tx.SendTimeout = 5000
    Tx.Connect(Host, Port)
    Msgs = Msg.Split(Chr(10))
    For x As Integer = 0 To Msgs.Length - 1
        If Msgs(x).Length = 58 Then
            ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msgs(x))

            ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
            '  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream = Tx.GetStream()
            CloseStream = True

            ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        Else
            If Not Msgs(x).Length = 0 Then
                WriteRTBLog("Error - Len - " & Msgs(x), Color.Red)
            End If

            Continue For
        End If
    Next

    If CloseStream = True Then
        stream.Close()
    End If
    Tx.Close()

    Return "OK" 'responseData
Catch ex As Exception
    Return "Error: " & ex.Message
End Try
```

Thanks for reading.

**More info:**
I get a log from the remote application (TCP dump) and some packets are incomplete, about 16bytes instead of 70.

Comment: You're never sending packets with TCP. You're sending a stream of bytes without boundaries. If "they" don't understand that they will typically claim to lose data or "receive multiple messages at once".

Comment: @usr Thanks for answer! So, as far you can see my code is ok? As far I know they are developing the TCP receiver on VB6 TCP socket; If they take too much time to capture the data an process it may losse some packets. Right? I'm gettin a lot of connection timeout about 70 per day.

Comment: At a quick glance it looks ok. You could try to concat all of your data into one big byte array and send it all at once. The array size would be [number of valid Msgs] * 58

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks for answer! So, no matter the amount of bytes, there's no limit at this level. They must reassemble all the packets no matter the order that they receive it and if the small packets have one part in one TCP packet and the rest in another TCP packet?

Comment: You don't have control of the TCP packet size and information, this is done on a different layer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, then they must to debug better their receiver.

Comment: "*I get a log from the remote application (TCP dump) and some packets are incomplete, about 16bytes instead of 70.*" So, call `read` again and get the rest. It's not TCP's job to implement the packet protocol, that's the application's job.